# WordPress core playlist function not showing artist and album info

Tags: shortcode, audio

On my test environment, all the information from the ID3 tags show up just fine on the playlists using the core MediaElement.js player.

```
http://labs.mixtapes.tv/audio/mixtapes/chris-webby-checkup-199.html
```

But on the live site, it doesn't.

```
http://www.mixtapes.tv/audio/mixtapes/chris-webby-the-checkup-8982.html
```

Same plugins, same album, same theme just two separate WP installations on the same server, I searched around, but couldn't really figure out why.

They're both using `[playlist]` shortcode in the template with the `do_shortcode` function.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[playlist tracknumbers=true" artists="true"]' ); ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the code so we can start thinking about what can be happening.

Comment: @cybmeta I added the code I'm using to call the player but that's not the problem, I figured out what the issue is, in my test environment, when I upload MP3s the fields in the WordPress media library get populated with the information from the ID3 tags, for some reason it's not doing that in the live environment though.

Comment: You have a typo: `tracknumbers=true"` should be `tracknumbers="true"`